# Determining parameters on crawler4j

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-crawler, crawler4j

I am trying to use crawler4j like it was shown to be used in [this](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/basic/BasicCrawlController.java) example and no matter how I define the number of crawlers or change the root folder I continue to get this error from the code stating:

"Needed parameters: 
     rootFolder (it will contain intermediate crawl data)
     numberOfCralwers (number of concurrent threads)"
The main code is below:

```
public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            if (args.length != 2) {
                    System.out.println("Needed parameters: ");
                    System.out.println("\t rootFolder (it will contain intermediate crawl data)");
                    System.out.println("\t numberOfCralwers (number of concurrent threads)");
                    return;
            }

            /*
             * crawlStorageFolder is a folder where intermediate crawl data is
             * stored.
             */
            String crawlStorageFolder = args[0];


            /*
             * numberOfCrawlers shows the number of concurrent threads that should
             * be initiated for crawling.
             */
            int numberOfCrawlers = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

There was a similar question asking exactly what I want to know [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001233/implementation-of-crawler4j) , but I didn't quite understand the solution, like where I was to type **java BasicCrawler Controller "arg1" "arg2"** . I am running this code on Eclipse and I am still fairly new to the world of programming. I would really appreciate it if someone helped me understand this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't giving any arguments when you are running the file, you will get that error.
Put the following as comment sin your code or delete it.

```
if (args.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("Needed parameters: ");
                System.out.println("\t rootFolder (it will contain intermediate crawl data)");
                System.out.println("\t numberOfCralwers (number of concurrent threads)");
                return;
        }
```

And after that set your root folder to the one where you want to store the meta data.

Answer (score 0):

To use crawler4j in your project you must create two classes. One of the them is CrawlController (Which start crawler according to the parameters) and the other is Crawler.

Just run the main method in the Controller class and see crawled pages

Here is Controller.java file:

```
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlConfig;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.fetcher.PageFetcher;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.robotstxt.RobotstxtConfig;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.robotstxt.RobotstxtServer;

public class Controller {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig2 = new RobotstxtConfig();

    System.out.println(robotstxtConfig2.getCacheSize());
    System.out.println(robotstxtConfig2.getUserAgentName());

    String crawlStorageFolder = "/crawler/testdata";
    int numberOfCrawlers = 4;
    CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
    config.setCrawlStorageFolder(crawlStorageFolder);

    PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
    RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();

    System.out.println(robotstxtConfig.getCacheSize());
    System.out.println(robotstxtConfig.getUserAgentName());

    RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
    CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, 
                 pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

    controller.addSeed("http://cyesilkaya.wordpress.com/");
    controller.start(Crawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);
  }
   }
```

Here is Crawler.java file:

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Page;
   import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler;
   import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL;

   public class Crawler extends WebCrawler {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
         // you can write your own filter to decide crawl the incoming URL or not.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Page page) {          
        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
        try {
        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
                System.out.println("URL: " + url);   
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse :
->Click on run
->Click on run configurations...

In the pop-up window :

First, left column: make sure that your application is selected in sub-dir Java Application, else create a new (Click on new).

Then in the central Window, go on "Arguments"

Write your arguments under "Program arguments" Once you have written your first argument press enter for the seconde arguments, and so on... (=newline because args is a [ ])

Then click Apply

And click Run.